# Tweepy authenticate with username/password

Tags: python, authentication, tweepy

I'm making a Twitter App in Python using Tweepy. I know how to use tokens but my assignment requires me to make it to allow a user to log in to Twitter using this app.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Having a user enter their username and password in a Tweepy application used to be possible with Tweepy's [`BasicAuthHandler`](http://www.tweepy.org/examples/basic_auth.html). However, this basic authentication is [no longer supported](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/52) in Twitter's API:

> Basic Authentication is deprecated and no longer supported on Twitter.

You can find more info on the deprecation of basic auth in the [Twitter API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/faq). Twitter now only supports OAuth, so unfortunately Tweepy is unable to serve as an interface for a login page using basic authentication.